# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'music'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem

I want to display a category (service) based on menu item value, so when the user clicks on music item for example it should fill the repeater from database table (ServiceP) where the name of the service = to the menu item value.

I tried this code, but I get an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'music'

This is the code when users clicks a menu item

```
 protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
 {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\PartyZone.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandText = "select * from ServiceP where 
     ServiceName = "+e.Item.Value.ToString() ;

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);

     d1.DataSource = dt;
     d1.DataBind();

     conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: it is hard to tell quite what you're doing at the moment because with the unterminated single-line string, that won't even compile. Can you clarify what is happening near that `where` and `ServiceName` ?

Comment: Also, what does the table look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually have:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select*from ServiceP where ServiceName="+e.Item.Value.ToString() ;
```

and `e.Item.Value` is `"music"`, then what you need here is a *parameter* to hold the value to search for, i.e.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select*from ServiceP where ServiceName=@value";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", e.Item.Value.ToString());
```

Note that you can also throw away the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - that does nothing useful here, and means you do the work twice.